# Using Cairo in a Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, cairo

I know [Cairo](http://cairographics.org) has support for Quartz output, but how would one implement such a thing in a Cocoa app?  I haven't really found any good examples of this being done in the documentation.

Comment: It somewhat seems like mixing apples & oranges. what's meant by `implement such a thing with Cocoa`?

Comment: I mean using this within a Cocoa app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain a `CGContextRef` from an `NSView` by calling `[[[myView window] graphicsContext] graphicsPort]`. You can then create a Cairo context from the `CGContextRef`.